# Sorting network in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, sorting-network

I am writing a basic program to realize the sorting algorithm in this link [Network for N=5, using Bose-Nelson Algorithm](http://jgamble.ripco.net/cgi-bin/nw.cgi?inputs=5&algorithm=best&output=text).

I compare two numbers by using comb.vhd component, the top entity of my program is in the code below.

I have no problem when I compile using Quartus, but when I use modelsim to simulate RTL, the output is always 0000, no matter what the inputs are.

I think that I misunderstood the use of signals, but I have no clue where it goes wrong.

Following is the main section of my program, the signals I am using are:

```
SIGNAL out0_temp, out1_temp, out3_temp, out4_temp               : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp1(0,1),comp2(3,4)
    SIGNAL out2_temp, out4_1_temp                                           : bit_vector (3 downto 0);  --comp3(2,4)
    SIGNAL out2_1_temp, out3_1_temp, out1_1_temp, out4_2_temp   : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp4(2,3),comp5(1,4)
    SIGNAL out0_1_temp, out3_2_temp                                     : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp6(0,3)
    SIGNAL out0_2_temp, out2_2_temp, out1_2_temp, out3_3_temp   : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp7(0,2),comp8(1,3)
    SIGNAL out1_3_temp, out2_3_temp                                     : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp9(1,2)
```

As showing in the algorithm, I am using 9 comparisons to sort inputs from the largest to smallest as below:

```
    BEGIN
comp1:comp -- (0,1)
PORT MAP (clk,reset, in0, in1, out0_temp, out1_temp);
comp2:comp -- (3,4)
PORT MAP (clk,reset, in3, in4, out3_temp, out4_temp);
comp3:comp -- (2,4)
PORT MAP (clk,reset, in2, out4_temp, out2_temp, out4_1_temp);
comp4:comp -- (2,3)
PORT MAP (clk,reset, out2_temp, out3_temp, out2_1_temp, out3_1_temp);
comp5:comp -- (1,4)
PORT MAP (clk,reset, out1_temp, out4_1_temp, out1_1_temp, out4_2_temp);
comp6:comp -- (0,3)
PORT MAP (clk,reset, out0_temp, out3_1_temp, out0_1_temp, out3_2_temp);
comp7:comp -- (0,2)
PORT MAP ( clk,reset, out0_1_temp, out2_1_temp, out0_2_temp, out2_2_temp);
comp8:comp -- (1,3)
PORT MAP ( clk,reset, out1_1_temp, out3_2_temp, out1_2_temp, out3_3_temp);
comp9:comp -- (1,2)
PORT MAP ( clk,reset, out1_2_temp, out2_2_temp, out1_3_temp, out2_3_temp);

out0 <= out0_2_temp;
out1 <= out1_3_temp;
out2 <= out2_3_temp;
out3 <= out3_3_temp;
out4 <= out4_2_temp;



END ARCHITECTURE behav;  

 Comp.vhd module
```

--Comp.vhd module is used to compare 2 numbers and switch them if th

```
LIBRARY ieee; 
USE     ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL; 
USE     ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL; 
USE     ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY comp IS 
    PORT ( 
        clk         : IN std_logic;  
        reset       : IN bit; 

          num0_in     : IN bit_vector (3 DOWNTO 0); 
        num1_in     : IN bit_vector (3 DOWNTO 0); 

          num0_out    : OUT bit_vector (3 DOWNTO 0); 
        num1_out    : OUT bit_vector (3 DOWNTO 0)  
    ); 
END ENTITY comp;

ARCHITECTURE compare OF comp IS 
BEGIN 
    PROCESS (clk, reset) 
    BEGIN

        -- reset everything to '0' when reset is asserted 
        IF (reset = '1') THEN 
           -- num0_out <=  (OTHERS => '0'); 
            --num1_out <=  (OTHERS => '0'); 

        ELSIF (rising_edge (clk)) THEN 

                -- num0_in is smaller than num1_in, so switch them 
                IF (num0_in < num1_in) THEN 
                    num0_out <= num1_in; 
                    num1_out <= num0_in; 
                -- num0_in and num1_in are in order 
                ELSE 
                    num0_out <= num0_in; 
                    num1_out <= num1_in; 
                END IF;

        END IF; 
     END PROCESS; 
END ARCHITECTURE compare;
```

Comment: I think any insight an answer could provide would require more of your code, particular visibility into your instantiated comp.

Comment: This is my comp module, it works fine, i simulated it by modelsim, it gives the expected results:

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a complete example of the code you are using to simulate, I created my own test bench using the `comp` entity you provided. Take a look to see if it is similar to your own:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity vhdl_tb is
end vhdl_tb;
architecture testbench of vhdl_tb is
  constant PERIOD         : time := 100 ps;
  constant TOTAL_CYCLES   : natural := 400;
  signal clk              : std_logic := '1';
  signal cycle            : natural := 0 ;

  signal done             : boolean := false;
  signal reset            : std_logic := '1';
  signal simclk           : std_logic := '0';

  SIGNAL out0_temp, out1_temp, out3_temp, out4_temp               : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp1(0,1),comp2(3,4)
  SIGNAL out2_temp, out4_1_temp                                           : bit_vector (3 downto 0);  --comp3(2,4)
  SIGNAL out2_1_temp, out3_1_temp, out1_1_temp, out4_2_temp   : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp4(2,3),comp5(1,4)
  SIGNAL out0_1_temp, out3_2_temp                                     : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp6(0,3)
  SIGNAL out0_2_temp, out2_2_temp, out1_2_temp, out3_3_temp   : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp7(0,2),comp8(1,3)
  SIGNAL out1_3_temp, out2_3_temp                                     : bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp9(1,2)

  signal in0 : bit_vector(3 downto 0) := "0001";
  signal in1 : bit_vector(3 downto 0) := "0010";
  signal in2 : bit_vector(3 downto 0) := "0011";
  signal in3 : bit_vector(3 downto 0) := "0100";
  signal in4 : bit_vector(3 downto 0) := "0101";

  signal out0 : bit_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal out1 : bit_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal out2 : bit_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal out3 : bit_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal out4 : bit_vector(3 downto 0);

  signal reset_bit : bit;

  component comp is
    port ( 
      clk         : IN std_logic;  
      reset       : IN bit; 
      num0_in     : IN bit_vector (3 DOWNTO 0); 
      num1_in     : IN bit_vector (3 DOWNTO 0); 
      num0_out    : OUT bit_vector (3 DOWNTO 0); 
      num1_out    : OUT bit_vector (3 DOWNTO 0)  
    ); 
  end component comp;

begin

  -- The following is a process which generates a clock
  -- while the unit is still under test
  ClkProcess: process(done,simclk)
  begin
    if (not done) then
      if (clk = '1') then
          cycle <= cycle + 1 ;
      end if ;
      simclk <= not simclk after PERIOD / 2 ;
    end if;
  end process;


  DoneProcess: process
  begin
    wait until (clk = '0');
      wait for PERIOD * 3;
      reset <= '0';
      wait for PERIOD * TOTAL_CYCLES;  -- Numder of cycles to execute
      done <= true;              -- Force the clock process to shutdown
    wait;                        -- This waits forever
  end process ;

  clk <= not simclk;


  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Test section
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  reset_bit <= to_bit(reset);

  comp1:comp -- (0,1)
  PORT MAP (clk,reset_bit, in0, in1, out0_temp, out1_temp);
  comp2:comp -- (3,4)
  PORT MAP (clk,reset_bit, in3, in4, out3_temp, out4_temp);
  comp3:comp -- (2,4)
  PORT MAP (clk,reset_bit, in2, out4_temp, out2_temp, out4_1_temp);
  comp4:comp -- (2,3)
  PORT MAP (clk,reset_bit, out2_temp, out3_temp, out2_1_temp, out3_1_temp);
  comp5:comp -- (1,4)
  PORT MAP (clk,reset_bit, out1_temp, out4_1_temp, out1_1_temp, out4_2_temp);
  comp6:comp -- (0,3)
  PORT MAP (clk,reset_bit, out0_temp, out3_1_temp, out0_1_temp, out3_2_temp);
  comp7:comp -- (0,2)
  PORT MAP ( clk,reset_bit, out0_1_temp, out2_1_temp, out0_2_temp, out2_2_temp);
  comp8:comp -- (1,3)
  PORT MAP ( clk,reset_bit, out1_1_temp, out3_2_temp, out1_2_temp, out3_3_temp);
  comp9:comp -- (1,2)
  PORT MAP ( clk,reset_bit, out1_2_temp, out2_2_temp, out1_3_temp, out2_3_temp);

  out0 <= out0_2_temp;
  out1 <= out1_3_temp;
  out2 <= out2_3_temp;
  out3 <= out3_3_temp;
  out4 <= out4_2_temp;


end testbench;
```

These are the results I got using modelsim:
[image: simulate waveform]

The code you've provided appears to work. So I would conclude your issue is with your simulation test bench.

Things to look out for:

- Make sure `clk` is defined in your test bench and it actually transitions...duh.
- Make sure your inputs (`in0` - `in4`) are defined and not all 0.
- Ensure your `reset` signal going into your comp blocks is defined. If it is not, the outputs of your comp blocks will be remain undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, see here is the rub.  I used your declarations and created the missing bits, and started before you posted your COMP.vhd:

```
entity comp is
    port (
        clk:    in  bit;
        reset:  in  bit;
        in0:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        in1:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);  
        out0:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        out1:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of comp is

begin
comparison:
    process (clk, reset)
        variable GT: bit;
    begin
        if in0 > in1 then
            GT := '1';
        else 
            GT := '0';
        end if;
        if reset = '1' then
            out0 <= (others => '0');
            out1 <= (others => '0');
        elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
            if GT = '1' then
                out0 <= in0;
                out1 <= in1;
            else
                out0 <= in1;
                out1 <= in0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;


entity bose is
    port (
        clk:    in  bit;
        reset:  in  bit;
        in0:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        in1:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        in2:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        in3:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        in4:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        out0:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        out1:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        out2:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        out3:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0);
        out4:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of bose is
    signal out0_temp, out1_temp, out3_temp, out4_temp: 
                    bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp1(0,1),comp2(3,4)
    signal out2_temp, out4_1_temp: 
                    bit_vector (3 downto 0);  --comp3(2,4)
    signal out2_1_temp, out3_1_temp, out1_1_temp, out4_2_temp: 
                    bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp4(2,3),comp5(1,4)
    signal out0_1_temp, out3_2_temp: 
                    bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp6(0,3)
    signal out0_2_temp, out2_2_temp, out1_2_temp, out3_3_temp:
                    bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp7(0,2),comp8(1,3)
    signal out1_3_temp, out2_3_temp:
                     bit_vector (3 downto 0); --comp9(1,2)
    component comp is
        port (
            clk:    in  bit;
            reset:  in  bit;
            in0:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);
            in1:    in  bit_vector (3 downto 0);  
            out0:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0);
            out1:   out bit_vector (3 downto 0)
        );
     end component;
begin
comp1:
    comp -- (0,1)
        port map (clk,reset, in0, in1, out0_temp, out1_temp);
comp2:
    comp -- (3,4)
        port map (clk,reset, in3, in4, out3_temp, out4_temp);
comp3:
    comp -- (2,4)
        port map (clk,reset, in2, out4_temp, out2_temp, out4_1_temp);
comp4:
    comp -- (2,3)
        port map (clk,reset, out2_temp, out3_temp, out2_1_temp, out3_1_temp);
comp5:
    comp -- (1,4)
        port map (clk,reset, out1_temp, out4_1_temp, out1_1_temp, out4_2_temp);
comp6:
    comp -- (0,3)
        port map (clk,reset, out0_temp, out3_1_temp, out0_1_temp, out3_2_temp);
comp7:
    comp -- (0,2)
        port map ( clk,reset, out0_1_temp, out2_1_temp, out0_2_temp, out2_2_temp);
comp8:
    comp -- (1,3)
        port map ( clk,reset, out1_1_temp, out3_2_temp, out1_2_temp, out3_3_temp);
comp9:
    comp -- (1,2)
        port map ( clk,reset, out1_2_temp, out2_2_temp, out1_3_temp, out2_3_temp);

    out0 <= out0_2_temp;
    out1 <= out1_3_temp;
    out2 <= out2_3_temp;
    out3 <= out3_3_temp;
    out4 <= out4_2_temp;
end architecture;

entity bose_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of bose_tb is
    signal clk:    bit := '0';
    signal reset:  bit := '0';
    signal in0:    bit_vector (3 downto 0) := x"A";
    signal in1:    bit_vector (3 downto 0) := x"5";
    signal in2:    bit_vector (3 downto 0) := x"9";
    signal in3:    bit_vector (3 downto 0) := x"4";
    signal in4:    bit_vector (3 downto 0) := x"7";
    signal out0:   bit_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal out1:   bit_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal out2:   bit_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal out3:   bit_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal out4:   bit_vector (3 downto 0);
begin
DUT:
    entity work.bose
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            in0 => in0,
            in1 => in1,
            in2 => in2,
            in3 => in3,
            in4 => in4,
            out0 => out0,
            out1 => out1,
            out2 => out2,
            out3 => out3,
            out4 => out4
        );
CLOCK:
    process 
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 120 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULIS:
    process
    begin
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 11 ns;
        reset <= not reset;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;

-- Network for N=5, using Bose-Nelson Algorithm.
--
-- o--^--------^--^-----------o
--    |        |  |
-- o--v--------|--|--^--^--^--o
--             |  |  |  |  |
-- o-----^--^--|--v--|--|--v--o
--       |  |  |     |  |
-- o--^--|--v--v-----|--v-----o
--    |  |           |
-- o--v--v-----------v--------o
--
-- There are 9 comparators in this network,
-- grouped into 6 parallel operations.
--
-- [[0,1],[3,4]]
-- [[2,4]]
-- [[2,3],[1,4]]
-- [[0,3]]
-- [[0,2],[1,3]]
-- [[1,2]]
--
-- This is graphed in 8 columns.
```

And ended up with a working simulation:

[image: bose_tb]
*(clickable)*

The only way I found you could get all '0's out was either by an error in comp, or an error in the test bench.

And notice I picked the same comparison order you used, although using ">" and opposite comparison order.

I though the reset didn't make sense, but actually used it.  And the reason it doesn't make sense is that you have to wait those 5 clocks anyway before the correct answer is guaranteed to be present.

This was done with ghdl and gtkwave.